# Parsing XML: Finding Interesting Elements Using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing, pubmed

I am using urllib and ElementTree to parse XML API calls from pubmed.

An example of this is:

```
#Imports Modules that can send requests to URLs 
#Python Version 3.4 Using IEP (Interactive Editor for Python) as IDE  
import urllib.request 
import urllib.parse 
import re 
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 
from urllib import request 

#Obtain API Call and assign Element Object to Root
id_request = urllib.request.urlopen('http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=1757056')
id_pubmed = id_request.read()
root = ET.fromstring(id_pubmed)
```

I now have been able to use Element Tree to import the data to the object root from ET.fromstring.  My issue now, is that I am having trouble finding interesting elements from this object.

I am referring to:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html
and my XML format looks like:
http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=1757056

I have tried:

```
#Parse Attempts.  Nothing returned.
for author in root.iter('Author'):
   print (author.attrib)
```

As well as

```
#No Return for author
for author in root.findall('Id'):
   author = author.find('author').text
   print (author)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to iterate by the tag

```
for author in root.iter('Item'):
    if author.attrib['Name'] == 'Author':
    print("Success")
```

Or:

```
author_list = [x for x in root.iter('Item') if x.attrib['Name'] == 'Author']
```

I don't know if you can iterate by attribute

Comment: Hmm, both are giving me invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The `.attrib` method returns the value inside of a tag. I think you may want to use either `.tag` or `.text` instead. I'm not exactly sure what data you are trying to pull from this tree, but you can also loop over the `author` value.

Edit:
Well the esummaryResult tag seems pointless, unless you will have more DocSum tags. But the information you want is in your `.text` value. Try printing `author.tag` and maybe you can check the values returned for what you currently are iterating over.

Comment: In this case, if you look at the XML link: http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=1757056 

I am trying to pull the Authors nested below Item Type = "List"  Name = "AuthorList"   

As in the XML, I am hoping to iterate over the three authors and use this method to then capture other interesting elements.